# Delete queries(deleting all information about an id) from different database is slow

Tags: php, mysql

Need help from you guys. I'm using MSQL. My application contains user information in multiple databases which contain so many tables. I need to delete user information for an id from all the tables which connects to different database.

I have written multiple delete queries in one file by connecting to all database(written at the top of the file) at the same time. I need to delete 4000 records related to the user. But till now only(from yesterday night the script was running) 150 records got deleted.

My requirement is to delete all the users coming under one group. So what i have done is:

- Get the group id
- Check if this group id exists, then retrieve all the users under this group.

  ```
  $sql = "select distinct user_id, fname, sname, email from ps.user_group_link where group_id in (SELECT group_id from ps.groups_main where tree_path like '".$path."%')";
  ```
- Now I connect to 3 database

  ```
      $dbt = db_connect('dB1','w');
      $dbm = db_connect('dB2','w');
      $dbmp = db_connect('dB3','w');
  ```

Then in `foreach` loop I'm writing all the delete queries from all tables from 3 database.

eg:(like below 20-30 delete statements are present)

```
$delete_classroom_records_sql = "DELETE FROM `table1`.classroom_records WHERE user_id=". $user;

$delete_classroom_records_res = $dbt->query($delete_classroom_records_sql);
```

But it seems the queries is taking too long for deletion.
Is there anything I have to take care for the query to run faster?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Check that a foreign key exists on user_id

Comment: This should be the comment not an answer.